# TabBar with reload UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have TabBar with UIWebView in each bar.

Usually in UIWebView where now TabBar placing Reload, Back, Forward buttons.
Now I can't find the way how to do it with TabBar.

I'd like to do it with popup menu with long holding one of TabBar buttons.
In popup menu I'll place Reload, Back etc

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

the UITabBarDelegate does have [didSelectItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar%3adidSelectItem%3a) method, but that will not give you a event if the user will hold the tab for some time.

but you could add a view to the view of the UITabBarController and add the Gesture Recognizer [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) (iOS 3.2+). For earlier iOS implement touchesBegan and touchesEnd of your custom view.

however i would choose a different design, because holding a tabbar for a while to trigger an action is nothing that user would easily find.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure it out. I thought about other disign. May be it's good idea